# GDB in a programming in C

Tags: gdb

I have a problem with a program in C. I need the absolute memory address of the local variables to the function main. I am debugging with the gdb.

How to know if there is an overflow in the variables.

Thank you

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef int16_t int16;

#include "mulaw.h"


void decodeFile(FILE * fIn, FILE * fOut, uint32_t samples) {

uint32_t i;

uint8_t * inSamples = malloc(samples * sizeof(uint8_t));
int16_t * outSamples = malloc(samples * sizeof(int16_t));

fread(inSamples, sizeof(uint8_t), samples, fIn);

for (i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
    outSamples[i] = 4 * muLaw[inSamples[i]];
}

fwrite(outSamples, sizeof(int16_t), samples, fOut);

free(inSamples);
free(outSamples);
 }

#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

char inputFile[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
char outputFile[MAX_FILE_SIZE];

FILE * fIn = NULL, * fOut = NULL;

struct header_t {
    char ChunkID[4];
    int32_t ChunkSize;
    char    Format[4];
} header;

char SubchunkID[4];
uint32_t SubchunkSize;

struct subheader_t {
    int16_t AudioFormat;
    int16_t NumChannels;
    int32_t SampleRate;
    int32_t ByteRate;
    int16_t BlockAlign;
    int16_t BitsPerSample;
    int16_t ExtraParamSize;
    int16_t Padding;
} subheader;



/* Usage */
if (argc != 3) {
    puts("Usage is: mulaw INFILE OUTFILE\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Careful here!!!!! */
strncpy(inputFile, argv[1], MAX_FILE_SIZE);
strncpy(outputFile, argv[2], MAX_FILE_SIZE);

/* Open input file */
fIn = fopen (inputFile, "rb");

/* Read main header */
fread(&header, sizeof(struct header_t), 1, fIn);

if (memcmp(header.ChunkID, "RIFF", 4) != 0
    || memcmp(header.Format, "WAVE", 4) != 0) {

    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown input format\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Read sub header */

while (fread(SubchunkID, sizeof(SubchunkID), 1, fIn)) {
    fread(&SubchunkSize, sizeof(SubchunkSize), 1, fIn);

    printf("Reading chunk of type %c%c%c%c (%d bytes)\n", 
        isprint(SubchunkID[0]) ? SubchunkID[0] : '?',
        isprint(SubchunkID[1]) ? SubchunkID[1] : '?',
        isprint(SubchunkID[2]) ? SubchunkID[2] : '?',
        isprint(SubchunkID[3]) ? SubchunkID[3] : '?',
        (int) SubchunkSize);

    if (memcmp(SubchunkID, "fmt ", 4) == 0) {
        /* read a fmt_ header */
        fread(&subheader, SubchunkSize, 1, fIn);

        /* we are going to adjust this header now to change the audio format */
        if (subheader.AudioFormat != 7) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Only mu-law audio input is supported\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* adjust audio format and bit depth */
        subheader.AudioFormat = 1;
        subheader.BitsPerSample = 16;

        /* fix derivative fields */
        subheader.ByteRate = subheader.SampleRate * subheader.NumChannels * subheader.BitsPerSample / 8;
        subheader.BlockAlign = subheader.NumChannels * subheader.BitsPerSample / 8;

        /* we don't write ExtraParamSize, because for AudioFormat == 1 it is not needed */
        SubchunkSize -= 2;

        /* Open file and write the header for our updated fmt_ chunk */
        fOut = fopen (outputFile, "wb");
        fwrite(&header, sizeof(struct header_t), 1, fOut);  /* Main header */

        fwrite(SubchunkID, sizeof(SubchunkID), 1, fOut);    /* Subheader */
        fwrite(&SubchunkSize, sizeof(SubchunkSize), 1, fOut);
        fwrite(&subheader, SubchunkSize, 1, fOut);

    } else if (memcmp(SubchunkID, "data", 4) == 0) {
        /* here is our mu-law data */

        /* write the header for our new chunk (it is twice as large) */
        int32_t tSubchunkSize = SubchunkSize * 2;
        fwrite(SubchunkID, sizeof(SubchunkID), 1, fOut);
        fwrite(&tSubchunkSize, sizeof(SubchunkSize), 1, fOut);

        /* process the data */

        (fIn, fOut, SubchunkSize);
    } else {
        /* unknown chunk, skipping */
        fseek(fIn, SubchunkSize, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}

/* Cleanup and exit */
fclose(fIn);
fclose(fOut);

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. Describe what is what you do and what is happening, tell us why you think there is an issue with your code. We don't know what you're doing on your computer, nor what you are seeing-

Answer (score 0):

Just run `gdb yourexe`

Then in gdb:

```
break main
run
p &inputFile
```

That will give you the address of `inputFile`: ex `$2 = (char (*)[256]) 0x62fd60`

To get the size of a variable you can use `p sizeof(variable)` or `p sizeof(type_of_the_variable>)`
That said, not sure if it will help you to track down your problem.

Comment: How I can see the size of the variables. For example of inputFile show directly, but for example the p &fIn is shown this: $3 = (FILE **) 0x7fffffffe240.

Comment: try `p(sizeof(fin))`

Comment: Thank you so much Jean-François. I have another problem. I want to modify uint8_t * inSamples = malloc(samples * sizeof(uint8_t)) with gdb to reverse 1073741824 bytes of memory in line 31 of the program. I have to fill the table with the data file offset, old value and new value.

Comment: it's better that you do it outside gdb! you have to [edit] your question because it started with questions on gdb and now it's something else. That's not the way it works here.

Comment: Sorry, Jean-François.

Comment: no need to be. I'm just telling how it works, no problem.

Comment: Jean-François, Could you help me with the problem of strncpy?

Comment: I have already done that you comment. I think that there is someting that I don't understand.

Comment: The exercise says: I have to substitute the lines:

Comment: strncpy (inputFile,argv[1],MAX_FILE_SIZE); y strncpy(outputFile,argv[2],MAX_FILE_SIZE);

Comment: sorry, that's becoming difficult like this. Can you ask anoher question specifically about that? (and make sure it's better because you don't want to be downvoted again:))

Comment: Hi, I found the solution. Thank you so much.